# unhandled error from mysql_next_result()

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

I'm running into an error, "unhandled error from mysql_next_result()", that I've never seen before and would appreciate any insight someone could provide.

I just upgraded my server to ColdFusion 9.  Around the same time I updated some scripts with a new feature that I'm now testing that uses tags surrounded by the @ symbol.  In my testing I have found that my scripts work without any of these tags, but fail with them.  Unfortunately, since this is handled in a single CFQuery within a CFTransaction block, it's hard to pinpoint the issue.  As near as I can tell the failing query is something like:

```
INSERT INTO galleries_images    (EID, Name, Desc1, Format1, OrderID, category, FullPath, hastags, haskeys, udate)
VALUES              (<CFQUERYPARAM CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" VALUE="#EID#">,
<CFQUERYPARAM CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" VALUE="#Name#">,
<CFQUERYPARAM CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" VALUE="#imageProps[2][2]#">,
<CFQUERYPARAM CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" VALUE="0">,
<CFQUERYPARAM CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" VALUE="#imageProps[2][4]#">,
<CFQUERYPARAM CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" VALUE="#catID.ID#">,
<CFQUERYPARAM CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" VALUE="#Source_Dir#\#Name#">,
<CFQUERYPARAM CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" VALUE="#hastags#">,
<CFQUERYPARAM CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" VALUE="#haskeys#">,
Now());
```

The values for these variables should be roughly:

```
 EID=24
 Name=Nick001@ord@001@ord@@tags@Pre-Ceremony@tags@.jpg
 imageProps[2][2]=
 imageProps[2][4]=001
 catID.ID=67
 Source_Dir=\Name=01_Nicholas - Camera\Nick001@ord@001@ord@@tags@Pre-Ceremony@tags@.jpg
 hastags=0
 haskeys=0
```

The same query (or set of queries, as 50-100 of these run in one CFQuery block) will run perfectly fine with a name and source_dir that has no @ symbols.  As these are within CFQueryParam tags I had thought they would be safe to use despite being related to variable declaration within MySQL.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I went back through and changed all the @ symbols in my code, and in all my imported filenames, to underscores.  I still received the same error which indicates that my earlier assumption about it being the @ symbol may have been incorrect...which leaves me more confused than ever.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: So what is mysql_next_result()?  is that your CF Function?

Comment: Limey, I've never heard of mysql_next_result() before this.  I assume it's a built-in MySQL function.  Though it's possible it's a ColdFusion or Java function called behind the scenes by CF.

Comment: Doesn't sound like a built in function, is sounds more developer generated.

Comment: Limey.  I don't recall ever defining or using that function.  It also doesn't sound anything like a name I'd use, and I'm the only developer on this project.  But I did a search through the entire codebase anyway just in case.  It came up empty.  So this is definitely either built into CF or MySQL.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tracked down the cause of this, and it was nothing like what I expected.  It turns out one of my database fields was 250 characters while the allowable filename length is 255 characters, and that was getting in my way.  When I increased the size of the database field everything began working.

I have no idea why I received a mysql_next_result() error instead of something more informative; perhaps it's a generic error.  Hopefully that little tidbit will help someone else in the same situation.